# Can't reset MySQL root password in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Ubuntu 18.04

Where am I wrong?

```
sudo service mysql stop 
sudo service mysql start --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `serviced` appends your parameter `--skip..` correctly to the binary. You should start `mysqld` directly to reset passwords, without using `serviced`.

Wrong:

```
sudo service mysql start --skip-grant-tables &
```

Right:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
```

Comment: It doesn't start properly. `ps ax | grep mysql` has two processes but after few seconds it becomes empty